# Is there a better way to do a group_by for each value in a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to find the best way to iterate through each column of a data frame, group by that column, and produce a summary. 
Here is my attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(
  a = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  b = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE),
  c = sample(LETTERS[3:15], 100, replace=TRUE),
  d = sample(LETTERS[16:26], 100, replace=TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

myfunction <- function(x) {
  groupVars <- select_if(x, is.factor) %>% colnames()
  results <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(groupVars)) {
  results[[i]] <- x %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = vars(groupVars[i])) %>%
    summarise(
      n = n()
    ) 
  }
  return(results)
}

test <- myfunction(data)
```

The function returns:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a         n
  <fct> <int>
1 A        37
2 B        34
3 C        29
...
...
...
```

My question is, is this the best way to do this? Is there a way to avoid using a for loop? Can I use purrr and map somehow to do this?

Thank you

Comment: `value` seems to be irrelevant here. Is that correct?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, that's right, can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape the data and group by both the column and the letter. This gives you one dataframe instead of a list of them, but you could get the list if you really want it with `split`.

```r
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(
  a = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  b = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE),
  c = sample(LETTERS[3:15], 100, replace=TRUE),
  d = sample(LETTERS[16:26], 100, replace=TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -value, names_to = "column", values_to = "letter") %>%
  group_by(column, letter) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
#> # A tibble: 35 x 3
#> # Groups:   column [4]
#>    column letter     n
#>    <chr>  <fct>  <int>
#>  1 a      A         33
#>  2 a      B         32
#>  3 a      C         35
#>  4 b      A          8
#>  5 b      B         11
#>  6 b      C         12
#>  7 b      D         14
#>  8 b      E          8
#>  9 b      F         17
#> 10 b      G         16
#> # … with 25 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I like this answer as I don't have to deal with lists and allows me to use summarise

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(data[1:4], ~data.frame(x = {{.x}}) %>% count(x))
#$a
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        39
#2 B        32
#3 C        29
#
#$b
## A tibble: 8 x 2
#  x         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        14
#2 B        11
#3 C        16
#4 D        10
#5 E        12
#6 F        10
#7 G        13
#8 H        14
#...
```

The output is a `list`. Note that I have ignored the last column of `data`, as it doesn't seem to be relevant here.

---

If you want columns in the `list` `data.frame`s to be named according to the columns from your original `data`, we can use `imap`

```
imap(data[1:4], ~tibble(!!.y := {{.x}}) %>% count(!!sym(.y)))
#$a
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        23
#2 B        35
#3 C        42
#
#$b
## A tibble: 8 x 2
#  b         n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 A        15
#2 B        10
#3 C        13
#4 D         5
#5 E        19
#6 F         9
#7 G        13
#8 H        16
#...
```

---

Or making use of `tibble::enframe` (thanks @camille)

```
imap(data[1:4], ~enframe(.x, value = .y) %>% count(!!sym(.y)))
```

Comment: `tibble::enframe` is a relatively new alternative to the `~data.frame(x = {{.x}})`, and doesn't need tidyeval/curly brackets

Comment: @camille Neat! I haven't quite caught up with the new `tidyverse` functions.

Comment: Even simpler than that: `enframe` defaults to a column called "name" and a column called "value". In this case, "value" will be "A", "B", "C", etc. So just `map(data[1:4], ~enframe(.) %>% count(value))` will suffice, or `data[1:4] %>% map(enframe) %>% map(count, value)`. (Clearly I don't think this is an important enough difference that I should post a separate answer!)

Comment: @camille Yes, I had played around with versions similar to the ones you've posted. In those cases, the `value` column will always be `"value"`. If you want the column name to reflect the column name from `data`, I think you need an `imap` approach and some NSE magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call:

```
apply(data, 2,table)
```

You can drop the last list element if you want.